# Ajax is not working at the time form submit using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form submit page, when the form is submitted I need to call Ajax. But now Ajax is not working. My main page is add_sale.php and the Ajax page is ajx_check_sale.php

My code :

add_sale.php

```
 function validate_form()
     {
     var cust_name= $('#cust_name').val();
     var total= $('#total').val();
      var sale_type= $('#sale_type').val();

     if(sale_type=='return')
     {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajx_check_sale.php',
        data:'cust_name='+cust_name + '&total=' + total,
        success: function(msg)
         { 

         alert(msg);
          /*if(msg==0)
           {

             alert("Return is greater then sale"); 
             return false;  
           } */
         }
      });
     }
    }
    <form action="" method="post" name="adFrm" onSubmit="return validate_form()">

    </form>
```

ajx_check_sale.php

```
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/variables.php");
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/functions.php");
 echo $cust_name=$_POST['cust_name'];
 echo $return=$_POST['total'];

 $cus="select sum(total) as total_sum from customer where id='$cust_id'";
 $cus2=mysql_query($cus);
 $fet=mysql_fetch_array($cus2);
 $total=$fet['total_sum'];

if($return>$total)
 {
     $status=0; 
     echo $status;  
 }
else
 {
      $status=1;    
      echo $status;     
 }
```

Comment: What is the error? Maybe it doesn't go success callback. Try to add error callback. So we can distinguish where the problem is.

Comment: check your network tab by pressing F12,and click on your ajax function in that tab and paste it here.

Comment: angular.min.js.map
ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib
GET
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Other
0 B
0 B
2 ms
-
jquery.min.map
ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib
GET
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Other
0 B
0 B
1 ms
-
angular-route.min.js.map
ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib
GET
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Other
0 B
0 B
Pending

Answer (score 1):

You can better use a JQuery listener and prevent the default action instead of calling it with `onSubmit`:

```
<script>

    $(document).on("submit", 'form[name="adFrm"]',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

         var cust_name= $('#cust_name').val();
         var total= $('#total').val();
          var sale_type= $('#sale_type').val();

         if(sale_type=='return')
         {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajx_check_sale.php',
            data:'cust_name='+cust_name + '&total=' + total,
            success: function(msg)
             { 

             alert(msg);
              /*if(msg==0)
               {

                 alert("Return is greater then sale"); 
                 return false;  
               } */
             }
          });
         }
    });

</script>


<form action="" method="post" name="adFrm">

    <input type="submit" name="yourSubmitButton" />

</form>
```

Comment: +1. I don't know if it's the only problem in this code. Indeed action is not catch (`preventDefault()`, `return;`). Moreover, a semi-colon was missing in `onSubmit()`. FYI: F12 is your friend :)

Comment: Doen't it execute the AJAX call or are you getting the wrong response? Please update your question with the whole code in `add_sale.php`

Comment: friend,add_sale.php have more code,beyond the limit of code post in stack overflow

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function add_sale.php:202
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'old_password' of undefined add_sale.php:384

Comment: So you try to read a property of an undefined variable. The property that has `old_password` is not assigned correctly.

Comment: This is jquery file <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: It's not the JQuery file which is wrong. It is a variable you assigned wrong. I can't give you the solution if i can't see the (relevant) code where the error is comes from.